# isnull for dynamically Generated column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, temp-tables, isnull

I am getting temp table with dynamically generated columns let say it is columns `A,B,C,D` etc from other source.

Now in my hand I have temp table with column generated. I had to write stored procedure with the use of temp table.

So my stored procedure is like

```
create proc someproc() 
as 
begin 
Insert into #searchtable 
select isnull(#temp.*,0.00) 
End
```

Now `#searchresult` is table created by me to store temp table columns. The problem arises when I want to check `isnull` for `#tempdb` columns. Because from source it comes it may be 3 columns, again next time it may be 4 columns. It changes.

Since it is dynamically generated I cannot use each column name and use like below:

```
isnull(column1,0.00)
isnull(column2,0.00)
```

I had to use all column generated and check if value is empty use `0.00`

I tried this below but not working:

```
  isnull(##temp.*,0.00),
```

Comment: Too broad... Please, add more details. You got one column that you insert into temp table, but then you use column1 column2 etc this part is not clear.

Comment: Iam getting temp table with dynamically generated columns let say it is columns A,B,C,D etc from other source..Now in my hand i have temp table with column  generated..I had to write storedprocedure with the use of temp table...So my stored procedure is like create proc someproc() as begin  Insert into #searchtable select isnull(#temp.*,0.00) End ...Now #searchresult is table created by me to store temp table columns..The problem arises when i want to check isnull for #tempdb column names..Because from source it comes it may be 3 columns,again next time it may be 4 columns.It changes..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with Dynamic code by fetching the column name for your dynamic table from `[database].NFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS`

```
--Get the Column Names for the your dynamic table and add the ISNULL Check:

DECLARE @COLS VARCHAR(MAX) = ''

SELECT @COLS = @COLS + ', ISNULL(' + COLUMN_NAME + ', 0.00) AS ' + COLUMN_NAME
FROM tempdb.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME LIKE '#temp[_]%' -- Dynamic Table (here, Temporary table)

DECLARE @COLNAMES VARCHAR(MAX) = STUFF(@COLS, 1, 1, '')

--Build your Insert Command:

DECLARE @cmd VARCHAR(MAX) = '
INSERT INTO #temp1
SELECT ' + @COLNAMES + ' FROM #temp'

--Execute:

EXEC (@cmd)
```

Comment: Thanks..I cannot touch this temp table which generates dynamically generated column..It is coming from some other sources..Now i had to write stored procedure with temp table.How can i write if all columns generated is null replace it with 0.00 ..I tried it with   isnull(#temp.*,0.00) but it doesn't work..Is their any alternative...

Comment: You can update table values to 0.00 after inserting the NULL? Share your complete query (with your Select and Insert statements)

Comment: Temp Table #Temp

Columns Generated A,B,C (Dynamically generated which comes from other source)

Values are 

A=10 B=null C=20 D...,Now i had to write sp

Create Proc SomeSp()
as

Insert into #searchtableresult 
select isnull(#Temp.*,0.00)


#Searchtable is the table which i created to store the results from temp table(According to my requirement).


Here if it normal table we can use like/

Insert into #searchtableresult
select isnull(A,0.00),isnull(B,0.00) and so.

Since it is dynamically generated columns problem arises..

Comment: The mentioned answer will create a query like `Insert into #searchtableresult select isnull(A,0.00),isnull(B,0.00) from #Temp` and will execute it. The `tempdb.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS` can show you the columns of #Temp.

Answer (score 2):

Hope, I understood your comment right:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE someproc
AS 
IF OBJECT_ID(N'#searchtable') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #searchtable

IF OBJECT_ID(N'#temp') IS NOT NULL
BEGIN

    DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max),
            @cols nvarchar(max)

    SELECT @cols = (
        SELECT ',COALESCE('+QUOTENAME([name])+',0.00) as '+QUOTENAME([name])
        FROM sys.columns 
        WHERE [object_id] = OBJECT_ID(N'#temp')
        FOR XML PATH('')
    ) 

    SELECT @sql = N'SELECT '+STUFF(@cols,1,1,'')+' INTO #searchtable FROM #temp'

    EXEC sp_executesql @sql

END
```

This SP checks if `#temp` table exists. If exists then it takes all column names from `sys.columns` table and we make a string like `,COALESCE([Column1],0.00) as [Column1], etc`. Then we make a dynamic SQL query like:

```
SELECT COALESCE([Column1],0.00) as [Column1] INTO #searchtable FROM #temp
```

And execute it. This query result will be stored in `#searchtable`.

Notes: Use [COALESCE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190349.aspx) instead of ISNULL, and `sp_executesql` instead of direct `exec`. It is a good practice.

Comment: Hey thanks ..Both answers worked for me..Unable to give 2 tick marks here..